# retry/cancel popup while refreshing the page-ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#

I'm having an image button as a templatefield inside a gridview.On clicking of the image button i will retrieve a pdf document from a folder location as byte array.The method will return null if the document is not available.after that if we try to refresh the page ,it throws retry/cancel popup.

The grid is inside an update panel and the update panel is having postback trigger for that image button.

Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this issues, you have to redirect to that particular page after clicking on that image button from the grid.
Please use following code after your code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Close", "javascript:window.location='" + Request.Url + "';", true);
```